# error with global name when running a script from another script - python

Tags: python, function, global

Let's say I have two scripts:

**test_fun1.py**

```
a = 1

def test1():
    print a
    execfile('test_fun2.py')

test1()
```

**test_fun2.py**

```
b = 2    

def print_a():
    print 'a'

def test2():
    print_a()
    print b

test2()
```

When I run `test_fun1.py` I get this error:

```
NameError: global name 'print_a' is not defined
```

If I exclude the `print_a()` within `test2()` both `a` and `b` are printed. Why would variables be set to global but functions wouldn't?

Comment: You mean both a and b are printed from test_fun2.py? (or could it be from test1())?  Also, have you considered just importing external scripts?

Comment: Maybe this can help you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904274/globals-and-locals-in-python-exec

Comment: @sihrc: a is printed from test1() and b is printed from test2() when print_a() is excluded from the code.

Comment: So, variables aren't "global" then.

Comment: @sihrc: what I meant was that I can use a and b inside the functions although they've been defined outside it. I haven't declared them global with the "global" command though.

Comment: Globals only need to be declared `global` if you assign to them. Otherwise, anything you assign to in a function is local, and anything you just read from is a closure variable or global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty interesting problem.  First a quick workaround, you can provide dictionaries to use as the local and global namespace when calling `execfile()`, using an empty dictionary for `globals` works fine:

```
# test_fun1.py
a = 1

def test1():
    print a
    execfile('test_fun2.py', {})

test1()
```

Alternatively, if you want the code to execute within the global scope of your module you can use `globals()` instead of `{}`.

Now on to why this isn't working... from the documentation on [`execfile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile):

> If both dictionaries are omitted, the expression is executed in the environment where `execfile()` is called.

Here "both dictionaries" is referring to the optional *globals* and *locals* arguments to `execfile()`.  In this case "the environment where `execfile()` is called" is the local scope of the function `test1()` in test_fun1.py.  Now it is reasonable to still expect this to work, because it seems like it should be doing something essentially equivalent to the following:

```
a = 1

def test1():
    print a
    # code executed by execfile
    b = 2    

    def print_a():
        print 'a'

    def test2():
        print_a()
        print b

    test2()

test1()
```

However there is a note later on in the docs:

> **Note:** The default *locals* act as described for function `locals()` below: modifications to the default *locals* dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function `execfile()` returns. `execfile()` cannot be used reliably to modify a function’s locals.

So there you have it, there is an explicit warning here that `execfile()` cannot be used to reliably modify a function's locals, and that is exactly what this code is attempting to do.  The `b = 2` and `def print_a(): ...` statements are executed within the scope of `test1()`, but they are not actually succeeding in adding those names to the namespace so attempting to access those names later on fails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm actually able to use b inside test2() - when the print_a() statement is removed from test2() both a and b are printed, so I can still access b. Does your explanation just apply to functions then?

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is kind of vague when it says "`execfile()` cannot be used reliably to modify a function's locals".  It very well could be that there is a difference here between variable assignment and function definitions, but I don't really know and I am not about to dig through the Python source code to find out.  The point here is that you should really be providing a *globals* argument to `execfile()` or the behavior will be inconsistent depending on where the call occurs.