# Python3-Issue with calling exec(open().read()) inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, exec

I'm having an issue with running a python script in a python script that i simply do not understand:

Assume we have 2 files in the same directory: 'init.py' and 'text.py'

init.py:

```
X = 5
print("init.py was run")
```

test.py:

```
exec(open("./init.py").read())
print("X = %s" %X)
```

If I run test.py now, I get

> init.py was run
>
> X = 5

However, if I change test.py into:

```
def func_call( filename):
  exec(open(filename).read())
  print("X = %s" %X)

func_call("./init.py")
```

I get:

> init.py was run
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 5, in
>
> ```
> func_call("./init.py")
> ```
>
> File "test.py", line 3, in func_call
>
> ```
> print("X = %s" %X)
> ```
>
> NameError: name 'X' is not defined

Can someone explain to me why this leads to different results?
Is there a workaround for this?
My goal is to initializes most of my variables by running a python script and accessing the variables set up in that python script.

Comment: Why don't you create file `const.py` and import it?

Comment: That actually works and solves the issue, thank you!

However I still don't understand why this is happening....

Comment: see also [NameError using execfile in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475760/3066295) and [What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [exec_documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

Inside method globals() and locals() are different objects:

```
def method():
    print(globals() == locals())
    exec('X=10')
    print('Method execution =', X)

method()
```

output:

```
False
NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

In global level this objects are equal:

```
print(globals() == locals())
exec('X=99')
print('Global exec =', X)
```

Output:

```
True
Global exec = 99
```

So If you want to do it via method, you need to pass the same object to exec. For your code it would look like this:

```
def func_call(filename):
  exec(open(filename).read(), globals(), globals())
  print("X = %s" %X)

func_call("./init.py")
```

Nevertheless, as I mentioned in comment, create file with consts and import it. Try to avoid using exec/eval at all costs, unless you are 100% sure what you are doing.